# Picture Transparency Object in PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

PowerPoint added native capability for picture transparency (*without having to create a shape*) [in late 2018](http://www.thepowerpointblog.com/image-transparency/). See that linked article to see what I mean.

I'm trying to figure out what/if an appropriate VBA object exists for it (there's not much online since it's a fairly new feature). I've tried the traditional [FillFormat.Transparency object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.fillformat.transparency), as well as a few other analogous attempts. (Basically, have been searching the VBA documentation up and down for an hour or two).

Any thoughts?

Comment: As the answers suggest there is no way to do that via VBA by now. In case you can manually edit your presentation and it won't be too much of a work to do it manually you could use the **"F4"** key to repeat the last action. For example: set one image to a transparency you want then select the next image which should have it and only hit **"F4"**. I know this is not a solution to anything you're asking just a help in case you end up doing it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to set the Picture Transparency directly (without using a Shape Fill). You would notice that the `Shape` properties are arranged somewhat as it appears on the Picture Tools Pane. For example, the Picture settings are on the last tab (where you have Picture Corrections, Color, Transparency and Crop). These are all accessible with the `Shape.PictureFormat` object. (The `.FillFormat` is only applicable when you are filling a shape).

You will notice the `.PictureFormat` has Properties relating to the aforementioned settings, except for Picture Transparency. The `.PictureFormat.TransparencyColor` cannot be used to set the degree of transparency.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerPoint VBA object model often lags well behind new features that appear in the user interface, so there's nothing available yet to do what you want.

Just a note, when it appears, transparency will be a *property*, not an object. The current TransparencyColor and TransparentBackground properties are for the old routine that creates a single picture color that is 100% transparent.